# How Do I Change the File Permission For Uploaded Files in WordPress?

Tags: uploads, media-library, server

I have a WordPress installation, where any files that are uploaded by the user via the media library are set to the permission level 600 on the server by default. This results in the file not being accessible after upload. Images will not be displayed for instance. And uploaded files cannot be downloaded.

What can I do to change the default file permission for uploaded files to something, so that the file can be accessed via the browser? (What permission level does it need and how can I make it default for any uploaded file?)

Comment: 600 should be fine, if the files are owned by the same the user that the website is running as. Which presumably the will be, if they were created by the website?

Comment: 4 = read and 6 = read+write, and the three digits mean: owner user, owner group, everyone else. So if you made it 644 then the web server can definitely read the files no matter who owns them. However if 600 isn't working then it sounds like something else is wrong, as the files ought to be owned by the web server process if it created them.

Comment: Why are these getting created as 600? This might be a global umask setting on your server or something in the web server config. Sorry I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: Yes, they are created as 600. I just checked, on all my other WordPress installations they are being created as 644.

Comment: I presume I can't fix this unless I have root access to the server, right?

Comment: It might be fixable in the Apache or NGINX config maybe. But no, if you aren't root on the server I'd ask whoever does manage it for help. However I still don't think there's any reason why 600 wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, when I change the permission from 600 to 644, it solves the problem. I'm not exactly sure how the server is configured, as I don't have root access, but 600 just doesn't seem to work.